# Why do I keep getting "Extra Argument in Call" for my initializer in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground, generics

I keep getting the error "extra argument in call" for repeatedValue in the init function. Why?

```
 class Point<T> {
/* n dimensional point
 multiline comments ...
*/
let point : [T]
init(dimensions: Int, rValue: Float = 0.0){
    self.point = [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue:rValue)

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The definition for init with repeatedValue is

`Array<T> init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)`

Your `rValue` must be of type `T`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the default value your T has also to be a FloatLiteralConvertible,
this:

```
Array<T> init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)
```

won't do it. This however will work and makes more sense since you don`t want points made out of for example "Cats" i guess...
Solution:

```
class Point<T:FloatLiteralConvertible> {
    /* n dimensional point
    multiline comments ...
    */
    let point : [T]
    init(dimensions: Int, rValue: T = 0.0 ){
        self.point = [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue:rValue)

    }
}
var pd = Point<Double>(dimensions: 10, rValue: 1.0)
var pf = Point<Float>(dimensions: 10, rValue: 1.0)
dump(pd.point)
dump(pf.point)
```